# How can I tell 'Whether a Javascript object exists on my page'?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I can't get the the conditional to work in this function, any help?

```js
function headupdate(id, name, heading)
{
    var order;
    if (document.getElementById(heading).value === undefined)
    {
        order = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        order = document.getElementById(heading).value;
    }
    alert(order);
    $.post('headingupdate.php', {id: id, name: name, value: heading, order: order},
        function(response)
        {
            $('#resume').html(response)
        }
    )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check as following.

```
var head = document.getElementById(heading);
if(head!=null)
{
  order = head.value;
}
else
{
order=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your post title, I use `typeof()` to find if an element exists in the DOM:

```
if(typeof(document.getElementById('someElement')=='undefined')) {
  alert('Element DNE');
}
```

Also, `typeof()` returns a string, so it needs to be in quotes for a conditional statement

```
"undefined"
```

Comment: nope, not working. I reversed it, typeof(document.getElementById('someElement').value=='string' is fine. however is the object i'm looking for is not on the page i get an error in the javascript. any other ideas?

Comment: `getElementById()` returns `null` if the element doesn't exist, and `typeof null` returns `"object"`, so I don't see how `typeof ... == "undefined"` works for you (it didn't work for me when I tried it).